How to reduce on-resistance and parasitic capacitance effects of my MUX setup?

I am designing a mux board to mux a flashing setup. Both UART and SPI lines are on 1.8V logic. The Mux chips have ~4-8ohms on-resistance and 1.7pF on-capacitance. Few questions:

Would I need buffers on each stage to reduce/eliminate attenuation or are these parasitic effects small enough for my setup?

Can a back of the envelope help me calculate/determine this? or would I need LTSPICE/ORcad to simulate this and/or bench setup to sniff data lines?

does amplifying the signal to make parasitic effects negligible before going into the muxes and then shifting it down at output can also be a solution?


lmk if there are other online resources that will point me in the right direction too...
Thanks in advance!

What frequency are you planning to run these busses at? For a 50 ohm driver, and such capacitive load, you can expect signal integrity issues beyond several 100 MHz. But if your driver is weaker....

Im transferring data at 20Mhz.
